# Требования для изучения ASP.NET CORE

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Какими базовыми (или же продвинутыми) знаниями нужно обладать что бы начать изучать ASP.NET Core (Допустим на том же Metanit). Я именно про навыки для изучения, а не про умение писать код.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Чтобы дать Вам совет, было бы неплохо, если бы Вы переформулировали вопрос, написав о своём уровне знаний. Например, о том, что Вы уже знаете такой то фреймворк - тогда Вам, возможно, будет проще перейти к изучению ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 3):

Думаю как минимум в теории нужно:

1. Уметь читать (наверно знаний RU/EN уровня средней школы достаточно)
2. Быть уверенным пользователем ПК и иметь представление о базовом (к примеру что такое оперативная память, как искать в гугле).
3. Понимать контекст того что ты изучаешь. Изучать веб фреймворк(к примеру  ASP.NET CORE) без базового понимания веба(понять как вообще все это высокоуровнево работает - что такое веб сервера, браузер, DNS, сайт, js\css, HTTP, и тд.) и языка программирования который будет использован для разработки(к примеру C#) - это нонсенс.
4. Иметь желание, терпение и много времени которое можно будет вкладывать в изучение на протяжении длительного периода (тут без конкретики).
5. Иметь копм на котором можно запускать свои программы и IDE. Практика нужна, если хотите потом использовать ASP.NET CORE. Просто прочитать и стать мастером не выйдет.